# Add JMenuItem to Already Visible JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am already listening to [MenuListener.menuSelected()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuListener.html#menuSelected-javax.swing.event.MenuEvent-) to know when a [JMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) is showing on the screen.  Initially, the `JMenu` has 1 [JMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) which says "Loading...".  After a slow operation, I add `JMenuItem`s to the `JMenu`.  The `JMenu` continues to show "Loading...".  If I select another `JMenu` and come back, then the JMenu shows the added `JMenuItem`s.  How do I cause the added `JMenuItem`s to show up immediately?

Here's the code which reproduces what is happening.

```
public class AddMenuItem extends JFrame
{
   private final JMenu m_menu = new JMenu("Edit");

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      new AddMenuItem().
         setVisible(true);
   }

   public AddMenuItem()
   {
      JMenuBar bar;

      bar = new JMenuBar();

      bar.add(m_menu);
      setJMenuBar(bar);
      setSize(600, 400);

      m_menu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener()
      {
         @Override
         public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e)
         {
            JMenuItem loading;

            loading = new JMenuItem("Loading...");

            loading.setEnabled(false);
            m_menu.removeAll();
            m_menu.add(loading);

            // This represents a long running task which updates the menu afterwards
            new Timer(5 * 1000, event -> updateMenu()).start();
         }

         @Override
         public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e)
         {
            // nothing to do
         }

         @Override
         public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e)
         {
            // nothing to do
         }
      });
   }

   private void updateMenu()
   {
      m_menu.removeAll();
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("1"));
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("2"));
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("3"));
      m_menu.revalidate();
   }
}
```

It seems that this [code example](http://javajon.blogspot.com/2014/07/add-jmenuitem-to-jmenu-after-menu-has.html) does exactly what I want but I am not sure what they are doing to make the visible menu repaint on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Initially, the JMenu has 1 JMenuItem which says "Loading...".

Code invoked from a listener executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. When you execute a long running task, it prevents the EDT from responding to events and repainting the GUI.

So to solve the problem the task started by that menu items needs to execute in a separate Thread. You might want to consider using a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the `EDT` and `SwingWorker`.

Edit:

> The problem is that once I know what to add to the menu, I don't know how to get the menu to show the added JMenuItems

You get the `JMenu` from the `MenuEvent` of your `MenuListener`:

```
JMenu menu = (JMenu)e.getSource();
menu.add( new JMenuItem( "Loading..." ) );
```

Edit:

Based on the SSCCE you can do something like:

```
   private void updateMenu()
   {
      m_menu.removeAll();
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("1"));
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("2"));
      m_menu.add(new JMenuItem("3"));
      JPopupMenu popup = m_menu.getPopupMenu();
      popup.pack();
   }
```

But remember because your long running task executes in a separate Thread, you would need to invoke the above code using a SwingUtiltities.invokeLater so that the code is executed on the EDT.

> It seems that this code example does exactly what I want but I am not sure what they are doing to make the visible menu repaint on the screen.

I think they are just hiding and showing the menu again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `m_menu.revalidate()`, do the following...

```
if (m_menu.isPopupMenuVisible())
{
   m_menu.setPopupMenuVisible(false);
   m_menu.setPopupMenuVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @camickr 's solution is better since it doesn't allow for any flickering of the popup menu.